Correspondence between Fock state and Slater determinant
Let's consider the application of a bra to a Slater determinant (I shall neglect all constant factors or signs because they are irrelevant to my question):
\begin{align}
\langle\varphi_{k_\beta}^{(N)}|\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
|\varphi_{k_1}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_1}^{(2)}\rangle & \cdots   & |\varphi_{k_1}^{(N-1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_1}^{(N)}\rangle\\[1.ex]
|\varphi_{k_2}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_2}^{(2)}\rangle & \cdots   & |\varphi_{k_2}^{(N-1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_2}^{(N)}\rangle\\[1.ex]
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots  & \cdots\\[1.ex]
|\varphi_{k_\beta}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_\beta}^{(2)}\rangle & \cdots  & |\varphi_{k_\beta}^{(N-1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_\beta}^{(N)}\rangle\\[1.ex]
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots  & \cdots\\[1.ex]
|\varphi_{k_N}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_N}^{(2)}\rangle &\cdots & |\varphi_{k_N}^{(N-1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_N}^{(N)}\rangle
\end{array}\right|
\end{align}
Applying cofactor expansion to the determinant along the last column, it can be proven that the result is:
\begin{align}
\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
|\varphi_{k_1}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_1}^{(2)}\rangle & \cdots   & |\varphi_{k_1}^{(N-1)}\rangle  \\[1.ex]
|\varphi_{k_2}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_2}^{(2)}\rangle & \cdots   & |\varphi_{k_2}^{(N-1)}\rangle \\[1.ex]
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots   \\[1.ex]
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots  \\[1.ex]
|\varphi_{k_N}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_N}^{(2)}\rangle &\cdots & |\varphi_{k_N}^{(N-1)}\rangle  
\end{array}\right|  
\end{align}
As can be seen, applying $\langle\varphi_{k_\beta}^{(N)}|$ to the determinant removes the $\varphi_{k_\beta}$ state, together with the last degree of freedom. This is exactly what we would expect the annihilation operator of fermion systems to do. So let us define:
\begin{align}
\hat{a}_{k_\beta} = \langle \varphi_{k_\beta}^{(N)}|
\end{align}
Then, take the Hermitian conjugate we can get the creation operator to be:
\begin{align}
\hat{a}_{k_\beta}^\dagger = | \varphi_{k_\beta}^{(N)}\rangle
\end{align}
In second quantization, we would expect $\hat{a}_{k_\beta}^\dagger$ to promote then $N-1$ system to the $N$ system. However, when we really do it, we get:
\begin{align}
|\varphi_{k_\beta}^{(N)}\rangle\left|\begin{array}{cccc}
|\varphi_{k_1}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_1}^{(2)}\rangle & \cdots   & |\varphi_{k_1}^{(N-1)}\rangle  \\[1.ex]
|\varphi_{k_2}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_2}^{(2)}\rangle & \cdots   & |\varphi_{k_2}^{(N-1)}\rangle \\[1.ex]
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots   \\[1.ex]
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots  \\[1.ex]
|\varphi_{k_N}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_N}^{(2)}\rangle &\cdots & |\varphi_{k_N}^{(N-1)}\rangle  
\end{array}\right|=\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
|\varphi_{k_1}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_1}^{(2)}\rangle & \cdots   & |\varphi_{k_1}^{(N-1)}\rangle & 0\\[1.ex]
|\varphi_{k_2}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_2}^{(2)}\rangle & \cdots   & |\varphi_{k_2}^{(N-1)}\rangle & 0 \\[1.ex]
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots  & \cdots\\[1.ex]
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & |\varphi_{k_\beta}^{(N)}\rangle\\[1.ex]
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots  & 0\\[1.ex]
|\varphi_{k_N}^{(1)}\rangle & |\varphi_{k_N}^{(2)}\rangle &\cdots & |\varphi_{k_N}^{(N-1)}\rangle & 0 
\end{array}\right|
\end{align}
The r.h.s. is not even a Slater determinant.
Can somebody give me a hint what went wrong? Thanks.
Lin-Hui Ye

Your identification that looks like $\hat a=\left<\varphi\right|$ will never work. You should instead consult some QFT condensed matter textbooks; quite many of them cover the proper way to convert from first quantised form to 2nd quantised form.

@naturallyInconsistent I actually looked up EKU Gross's Many Particle Theory book but did not get an answer. I always use $(|\varphi\rangle)^\dagger = \langle \varphi|$. I am puzzeled why it does not work here.

It cannot work because you are using a first quantised quantity as if it were a 2nd. I know Fetter & Walecka, and Bruus & Flensberg, both cover the topic. Both are well-written

@naturallyInconsistent mathematically $\hat{a}{k\beta}^{(N)}=\langle \varphi_{k_\beta}|$ does convert an $N\times N$ Slater determinant into the $(N-1)\times (N-1)$ one.  As said, it removes the $\varphi_{k_\beta}$ state as well as the last degree of freedom of the particles,. To my understanding These are exactly what the annihilation operator does. I don't know why you say $\varphi_{k_\beta}^{(N)}$ will never work as the annihilation operator.

It will never work because you need an operator. An operator that how many $N$ you are having, it just creates to $N+1$ or annihilates to $N-1$; your thing will only work one way and for one of these $N$, not any $N$. In particular, you should not have a function that isn't an operator, try to do what an operator should be doing. Once you see the proper treatment, you will fully understand why your scheme will not work.

I know the formal way is to start from Fock space and occupation number representation. I am just trying a new way of converting 1st quantization to 2nd by cofactor expansion. I am not even sure where there is a one-to-one correspondence between the Fock vector (non-interacting) to a Slater determinant. I guess one cannot make one-to-one derivation between the 2 languages.

That is correct. You absolutely require the correct apparatus to deal with these things. But you can choose any 1-particle basis for the expansion, and so you can be arbitrarily close. Not sure what happens to the deviations from 1-particle basis when you have more than one particle, though.

@naturallyInconsistent "An operator that how many N you are having, it just creates to N+1 or annihilates to N−1; your thing will only work one way and for one of these N". This is really clever! I now fully understand why $\varphi_{k_\beta}^{(N)}$ is not $\hat{a}{k\beta}$. Thanks a lot for the claficication.

I've no remaing questions. This topic can be closed. @naturallyInconsistent Thank you very much!
